# Get Response body from play.api.mvc.Action[AnyContent] in Play framework (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following Play (Scala) code:

```
object Experiment extends Controller {

 //routes file directs /genki here
 def genki(name: String) = Action(pipeline(name))

 def pipeline(name: String) = {
   req:play.api.mvc.RequestHeader => {
      val template = views.html.genki(name)
      Experiment.Status(200).apply(template).as("text/html")
   }
 }

 def simple = Action {
   SimpleResult(
      header = ResponseHeader(200, Map(CONTENT_TYPE -> "text/plain")),
      body = Enumerator("Hello World!".getBytes())
   )
 }

}
```

This compiles fine and works as expected.

Using the scala REPL how can I display the actual html?

I have:

```
 scala> val action = simple
 action: play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] = Action(parser=BodyParser(anyContent))
```

which I take to mean that now the value reference 'action' in the REPL is an Action object which is type-constrained for AnyContent (is that correct way to say it?).

how can I now use this Action to print out the Http Response html content?

Many thanks

Comment: I am sorry but the question is unclear to me. You wish to print the final html response on repl?

Answer (score 6):

Rather than the manual result extraction vptheron describes, you can use `play.api.test.Helpers`:

```
import play.api.test.Helpers._
val result: Future[SimpleResult] = …
val bodyAsBytes: Array[Byte] = contentAsBytes(result)
```

There's also `contentAsString` etc.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the [answer by Huw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445213/243233), here is the full working code:

```
import play.api.test._  
def getStringFromAction(action:Action[AnyContent]):String = {
  val request = new FakeRequest("fakeMethod", "fakeUrl", new FakeHeaders, "fakeBody")
  val result = action.apply(request).run
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  Helpers.contentAsString(result)(1000 millis)
}
```

You will need to include the following libraries (not included by default in Play): `play-test_2.11.jar`, `selenium-java.jar`, `selenium-api.jar`, `selenium-chrome-driver.jar`, `selenium-firefox-driver.jar`, `selenium-remote-driver.jar`, `selenium-htmlunit-driver.jar`, `fluentlenium-core.jar`, `htmlunit-core-js.jar` and `htmlunit.jar`. These are available in the Play or Activator distribution. You can also add a dependency in build.sbt as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24850328/243233).

Comment: @Jus12 Do you know how to make your answer work with Play 2.5?  FakeRequest has gone away, replaced by RequestBuilder, and the above code now wants an Akka Materializer too.  Since upgrading to 2.5, the above code no longer compiles.

Answer (score 2):

`Action` does not have a content since it's an object that you can use to apply a `Request` and get a result.

```
val request: Request[A] = ... // create a request instance
val resultFuture: Future[SimpleResult] = simple(request)

val bodyAsBytes: Array[Byte] = Await.result(Await.result(resultFuture, timeout.duration).body |>>> Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]](), timeout.duration)
```

Note that for your example an empty request is enough since you don't use it.

Also, notice that `body` from `SimpleResult` is an `Enumerator`, you need to apply an `Iteratee` to it, here I'm just applying a consumer to get the whole list. The 2 `Await.result` are used:

1. to wait for the `Future[SimpleResult]` to be complete
2. to wait for the `Enumerator` to be done sending data to the `Iteratee`.

Comment: thanks, how do I instantiate a new Request[A] object, and what is the [A]? I think this is a type class constraint but I don't get the 'A'. a lot of my unclarity with Scala is not knowing when we are in OO mode or FP mode!

Comment: The `A` is whatever you want, it's a type parameter to be provided to the type constructor to create a concrete type. For you example you can look at `play.api.test.FakeRequest`, it's provided by Play! to make unit testing easier.

Comment: thanks, I did notice there was a play.api.test.FakeRequest in the api docs but I can't import it on the repl or in my code which I guess means it is not shipped with the standard play distro..

Comment: @user3231690 you need to include the library play-test_2.xx.jar (where xx is your play version).