# How do I extract a result String from a Play 2.5 Action[AnyContent]?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have a Play Application that extends Controller.

Before Play 2.5, I used to be able to do the following, per @Jus12's answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436155/get-response-body-from-play-api-mvc-actionanycontent-in-play-framework-scala):

```
import play.api.test._
def getStringFromAction(action: Action[AnyContent]): String = {
  val request = new FakeRequest("fakeMethod", "fakeUrl", new FakeHeaders, "fakeBody")
  val result = action.apply(request).run
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  Helpers.contentAsString(result)(1000 millis)
}
```

But after upgrading to Play 2.5, the above code no longer compiles.

At the line:

```
  val result = action.apply(request).run
```

the errors are:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter materializer: akka.stream.Materializer
not enough arguments for method run: (implicit materializer: akka.stream.Materializer)scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result].
Unspecified value parameter materializer.
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get this working.

I have a GET action that works fine.  It returns an Action[AnyContent].

I'm having trouble with the POST action.  The POST action is an `Action(parse.json)` that returns an `Action[JsValue]`.  I call the GET action, which already knows how to get a computed JSON answer from a separate JAR, I get an `Action[AnyContent]` from the GET action, but now I need to get the String out of the result body so I can pass it back via `Ok(stringValue)`.

Comment: You should probably inject the Play Materializer into your class:
`class MyComponent @Inject() (implicit materializer: Materializer) {...`
You might be needing the ExecutuionContext as well. Inject it the same way.